# How can I change the fontsize in excel365 vba Project Window?

Tags: excel, vbe

I know how to change the EDITOR code window font but cannot find a way to change the font in the other windows. I don't want to change the screen resolution as I usually have other apps open as well.
I am quite happy to edit the registry if only I knew what to edit.

Answer (score -1):

Good Day,

- Access "Tools" Menu Then "Options..."

[image]

- Editor Format Tab

[image]

- Change the Size option

Comment: The reply shows how to change the font and its size in the EDITOR window only. I would like to change them in  the other vba windows.